# Shortest path on graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, oc.optimization-and-control

I would like to now if there has been any work on related problems, that is, shortest path problem in dynamically evolving graphs.

Comment: As you see, there has been. Can you be more specific in what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge literature on shortest paths in dynamic graphs.  Try this Google search to start:
https://scholar.google.be/scholar?cites=11260993909169863538&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en